# How to get the class that extends Base class from within Base class using generics?

Tags: android, generics, inheritance

I have a `BaseAdapter` class where I am implementing a "refresher" for the list data in all Adapter classes that extend BaseAdapter, as follows:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof "Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter") {
            ((Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter") adapter).refreshData(data);
        } else {
            adapter = new Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter"();
            (("Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter") adapter).refreshData(topicDetails);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

where `refreshData(T data)` is a generic, abstract method also in `BaseAdapter` that implements the `notifyDataChanged` etc.

So that in the clss that extends `BaseAdapter`, I can just call:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Data> {

        @Override
        public void refreshData(Data data) {
            insertItems(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

And in the Activity/Fragment or wherever the RecyclerView is:

`mRecyclerView.refreshData(mAdapter)` or something. I'm not sure how to get the "Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter" from within BaseAdapter

**tldr**

Basically I want to write a generic method for doing:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof "Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter") {
            ((Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter") adapter).refreshData(data);
        } else {
            adapter = new Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter"();
            (("Adapter Class that extends BaseAdapter") adapter).refreshData(topicDetails);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

so that I don't have to do this for every List

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this case is related to **inheritance** that you use. Here you can use **generic inheritance** like this:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mRecyclerView.getAdapter();

if (adapter instanceof BaseAdapter) {
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).refreshData(topicDetails); //You will get unchecked call here but it won't cause a problem
} else {
    adapter = new BaseAdapter<>();
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).refreshData(topicDetails); //You will get unchecked call error here but it won't cause a problem
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my BaseAdapter class.

```
/* general recyclerview adapter */

public abstract class BaseRecyclerAdapter<T, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    public final List<T> itemList;
    public OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public BaseRecyclerAdapter(List<T> itemList, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public BaseRecyclerAdapter(List<T> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    public void clear() {
        itemList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void add(List<T> itemListToAdd) {
        itemList.addAll(itemListToAdd);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener<Object> {
        void onItemClick(View view, Object object);
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
public class AdapterDemo extends BaseRecyclerAdapter<BeanCart,AdapterDemo.MyViewHolder> {


    public AdapterDemo(List<BeanCart> itemList) {
        super(itemList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you will pass two class type

> T> List type
>
> VH> View holder

Like this `public class AdapterDemo extends BaseRecyclerAdapter<BeanCart,AdapterDemo.MyViewHolder>`